# Convert image annotation XML file to TXT file

Tags: xml, python-3.x, text

I have some xml files having image annotation data. I want to convert these xml files to .txt files.

I have made the script to convert xml to txt file in python but facing an error

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import sys
import os
import glob
from glob import glob

def read_xml(f,op):

    if not os.path.exists(op):
        os.makedirs(op,exist_ok=True)

    file_n = glob(f)
    for i in range(len(file_n)):
        xcontent = ElementTree()
        xcontent.parse(file_n[i])

        doc = [xcontent.find("folder").text,xcontent.find("filename").text,xcontent.find("path").text,xcontent.find("width").text,
            xcontent.find("height").text,xcontent.find("depth").text,xcontent.find("name").text,xcontent.find("xmin").text,
            xcontent.find("ymin").text,xcontent.find("xmax").text,xcontent.find("ymax").text]


        out = open(file_n[i]+".txt","w")
        out.write(op)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    files=("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\images\\train_xmls\\*")
    op_path=("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\images\\train_xmls_op")

    read_xml(files,op_path)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/128938/PycharmProjects/augmentation_code/test_file.py", line 32, in <module>
    read_xml(files,op_path)
  File "C:/Users/128938/PycharmProjects/augmentation_code/test_file.py", line 17, in read_xml
    doc = [xcontent.find("folder").text,xcontent.find("filename").text,xcontent.find("path").text,xcontent.find("width").text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

You are calling `.text` on a `None` value. That means one of your `.find()` calls did not find anything.

Use a helper function to extract the text value, like this:

```
def text_content(element):
    if element:
        return element.text
    return ''
```

and then

```
text_content(xcontent.find("folder"))
```

Comment: Hi...thnx for your reply. Well i am a bit new to python. Can you please guide me by telling what changes exactly need to be made in my script?

Comment: I think you will figure it out on your own, I've given you all the pieces. And you wrote the code in your question, after all.